# Running Java Threads on a Different Server/JVM

Tags: multithreading, web-services, jakarta-ee, jvm

I'm have a working Java EE application that runs a multitude of threads. I want to move these threads off my application and simply have access to their data (Strings and ints).

How should I achieve this if I want to say call a method on my web application that accesses a threads data on a different server/JVM?

Comment: threads cannot be moved. You can only destroy them here and create there.

Comment: Threads' data are changing, so having access to threads' data is a questionable pleasure. Better program threads so that they put their data in some sort of output queue.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov   why can't i just create a web service that allows me to access these threads?

Comment: @the1.8gpaProgammer you can provided they are in the same JVM.

Comment: As the other answers have stated, what you're trying to do is not really possible, at least not in the way you're describing it. For the problem you appear to be trying to solve however, there are standard enterprise architecture designs that would let you offload the bulk of processing overhead to a physically different machine or java process, with you retrieving the results remotely

Answer (score 0):

> accesses a threads data

In Java almost all data is on the heap, which is shared by many threads. Very little of it is scoped completely to an individual thread. So the very idea of moving a thread and only "its data" does not make much sense.

And it's not just Java, pretty much any language with shared mutable state will face the same issues.

Of course your application can have a concept of thread-owned data, but that would be application logic and not part of java itself or its Thread class.

Answer (score 0):

Say you wanted to separate these layers (perhaps put them on different machines or for scalability) you would  separate the data layer from your presentation layer and put them in different JVMs. You make the data layer provide a service to the presentation layer.  How you do this depends on your preferred transport. e.g. it could be a web service, or you can use RMI, JMS, TCP, shared memory.

In any case, one JVM can only access the data of another process through services that JVM exposes. (Except in the case of shared memory, but it's not easy to get this working unless your data model is very simple)

Comment: I am now thinking or using some kind of third party web service api. So that I don't have to create an entirely new web service for my application(pay for server space, data storage etc). Is there something like this out there where I could put in say www.timerserviceapi.com/webapi/setatimer/timerid=1?setseconds=230

Comment: then in my enterprise application simply remotely  access that timers data

Comment: It's an interesting service, very simple to implement. There might be something but I would do this yourself.  Note: how do you ensure the ids are unique? I would use a UUID.